# How can i tokenize all rows in a specific column from a csv file using Python?

Tags: python, pycharm, spyder, tokenize, sentiment-analysis

I'm doing a sentiments analysis using Python (I'm still a rookie with this specific programming language). I have some Twitter data in a csv file that I need to pre-process before doing the real analysis. First of all I need to tokenize the text from a specific column, in my case the second or col B. I found some suggestions how to do the tokenization but not to pick the specific col. Anyone who has experience with this?

I tried this code, which seems to work for all columns, but how can I isolate it to the second col?

```
import csv
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize 

with open('TwitterData.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
   reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
   for row in reader:
       print(row)
```

Any suggestions to modules and code that works for pre-processing to sentiments analysis?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is?

Comment: Yes of course :) In my csv file I have comma seperated columns and the second column is the one that holds the tweets that I want to tokenize (each row contains one tweet). When I run the code it tokenizes all columns, including source, date time etc. (each tweet has other relevant data attached to it in other columns - I don't want to tokenize it though). Hope this makes more sense? :)

Comment: @AMC was that more clear? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can highly recommend you the scikit-learn documentation and modules, especially the part about "Working with Text Data": https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html

There they also have a section about sentiment analysis: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html#exercise-2-sentiment-analysis-on-movie-reviews

If you need more specific help with your code, it is alway best to provide a "minimal reproducable example": https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
This way, others can help you better with a specific issue you are facing.

I hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely try it out and see if it is relevant to my case :)